# How to make a path relative to main program exe?

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm creating an app that takes some pre-determined images to be displayed.

So far I've been using the following

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\program-name/drawings/image1.png";
```

But I'm thinking about making it more versatile, and instead, make `pictureBox1.ImageLocation` dig up a path, "from" where the current .exe is.

Something like the following:

```
 pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "/drawings/image1.png";
```

This is not working.

```
   pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "./drawings/image1.png";
```

Is not working either (Have read around that `.` makes up its relative path).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why is `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` "not working"?

Comment: Consider to add images to application resources

Comment: Doesn't load the image

Comment: What path does it yield?

Comment: @CodeCaster Funny, it returns exactly the correct path. And I double checked the image, and its there, It doesnt load. LOL

Comment: Not sure if it is that important, but shouldn't it be ... + "\drawings\image1.png" ? with a backslash?

Comment: I've tried it all, nothing is working

Comment: Can you put everything together and give us the exact output? Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\drawings\image1.png";

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

instead of Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) ?

Comment: It  says `Assembly` does not exist in the current context. But are you trying to tell me there's nothing wrong in my first attempt? Does path.GetDirectoryname returns a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @".\drawings\image1.png";
```